# What is meaning of "a long way from being"?

Tags: idioms

> Question: Is it bad?
>   Answer: "I've suggestions but this is a long way from being bad"

What does this **a long way from being** mean? Does it mean "much more than just bad" or does it mean "not bad at all"?

Comment: “*Does it mean "much more than just bad"*” — No, that would be "*is far beyond being bad*".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, I am not sure whether *I have suggestions* can be shortened to *I've suggestions*, it sounds awkward, I've never heard such a statement. If you want it shortened, it'd maybe be a good idea to write it as *I've got a few suggestions*.

*Long way from being bad* means it's not bad (yet): this situation would need to get a lot worse to become bad.

The answer in your quote says that the situation is still *OK*.

Comment: I think it's just about possible to shorten: "I've a good idea" sounds OK, at least. Someone on [Quora](https://www.quora.com/Is-Ive-a-gramatically-correct) suggests "I've a" is more UK than US.

Answer (score 1):

This is in a sense of a long way from becoming, which means not at all.

Answer (score 1):

to be bad
to be good
to be rich
to be poor
etc. **ad nauseam**

to be a long way from being bad.

The parse is not "a long way from being"

It's "a long way from being bad"

**a long way** = **not close to**

Being bad is not a good thing.
Being rich can be pleasant.

Being pleasant is a long way from being rude.

Comment: I am puzzled at the down vote on your answer. It is correct, and pleasing to read.

Comment: @EllieKesselman It's because it is not high falutin' enough for this forum and straight to the point. Also, the question is not really suited for this site. I parse texts for a living and some people resent that. :)

Answer (score 0):

Although one needs more context to answer with assurance, I can imagine the conversation going like this:

Alice says: "Here's what I plan to do."

Alice outlines a plan, then asks:  "Is it bad?"

Barb says: "I have some suggestions, but it's a long way from being bad."

Clearly, the meaning of Barb's reply is neither "it's worse than bad" nor "not bad at all", but somewhere in between.

"It's a long way from being bad" appears to be analogous to  "It sure fails to suck" or to "No way is that plan a total fail!"